# Sequence diagram change states

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I need to draw sequence diagram for this:

```
Draw sequence diagram depicting the following scenario:
• Pressing the 'Hot' button
• Wait for 6 seconds (not shown in the diagram)
• Activating child protection
• Pressing the 'Hot' button
• Click on 'Safety'
• Pressing the 'Hot' button
• Wait for 6 seconds (not shown in the diagram)
• Pressing the 'Cold' button
```

I'm not sure if the result really reflects and how to specify the parameters in this chart
Does the graph reflect the above scenario
[image]

Comment: An interaction is not  the right support for the sequence of actions you want to show, so a sequence diagram is not the right way. You speak about *state*, what about a state machine if you really have states ?

Comment: All your messages from the textual description are shown, but there are more and they are strange: What is `timeout5000/hotWaterOff()`? Why is it sent from Water bar to itself? It looks like the notation of state transitions. Did you want to use duration constraints? There are no parameters in your description, but if you add them, you can show arguments for them in the round brackets.

Comment: You can show states in a sequence diagram, but they have the normal shape: rounded rectangles. What you are drawing is a non state based state invariant. That is Ok, but I think the textual syntax for the constraint is strange. What does a word before the square brackets mean? A syntax closer to OCL would be `{inState(hot) and not protected}`.

Comment: The title of your lifelines is underlined. The current UML says, they are not underlined. This is because the title includes the role and the type of the represented object, and roles are not underlined in the other diagram, that can show them: composite structure diagrams. Only the title of instance specifications is.